# Find deleted Organizational Unit Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I really need help right now. In AD DC one of our organizational units named "Columbus" is missing. It has Users in the unit, and now the Users and the Organizational unit is now missing.  I searched for Users from Forest root, with out any luck. How do know undelete the organizational unit and/or users. Please for example.

I found the PS example, but I do not know how to filter organizational Unit.

> Get-ADObject -SearchBase "CN=Deleted
>   Objects,DC=Jones-Stuckey,DC=Local"
>   -ldapFilter:"(msDs-lastKnownRDN=Columbus)" –IncludeDeletedObjects –Properties lastKnownParent

Comment: http://www.quest.com/object-restore-for-active-directory/

Comment: Greg Yes.  I found the organizational unit and users. When I recover them, none of their Memeber of are correct. How would I restore Member of to each recovered user?

Comment: Do you have the Recycle Bin feature enabled?

Comment: You're saying that the user's group memberships are not there?

Comment: You are correct. I can see users. They are disabled with no Membership except Domain USer

Answer (score 1):

I believe this TechNet article has all the steps you need to do a restore of your OU:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379542(v=ws.10).aspx

> In Windows Server 2003 Active Directory and Windows Server 2008 AD DS, you could recover deleted Active Directory objects through tombstone reanimation. Introduced in Windows Server 2003, tombstone reanimation took advantage of the fact that Active Directory kept the deleted objects in the database for a period of time before physically removing them.

(Credit to the engineer that termed this "tombstone reanimation".)